# Media player and accessibility, beyond the big buttons

Tags: usability, accessibility

I have to layout a media player for a touchscreen in hospital. The main feature has to be the accessibility. The touchscreen is thought to be near the bed of sick people. Not only invalid people but general sick people (so i think that also relaxing color palette could be an issue).

I am not very much in the field of user experience so i'm asking here for some advice that go beyound my idea of "big buttons".

Of course i'm also interested in the psycological/gestalt/usability law beyound the advice, on the answer.

#### EDIT:

The touchscreen dimension are like a 13" screen and the resolution in 1024x768. The player of course will be at full screen mode.

The important part of the gui is that all elements (volume slider, playlist items, pause stop play, progress bar) must be clickable with the fingers (and that's why i thought to "big buttons") for a persona that is lying down on bed. Particular kind of motion disability are not important for the standard prototype available to all the patients.

Comment: please comment the motivation of downvote

Comment: i have no idea why there's a downvote, since I find this really a difficult yet interesting question --–  maybe "speech recognition" and/or gestures could be some alternative approach – or?

Comment: I downvoted because the question doesn't show any own research or effort. As it stands, I think there is not enough material to go on for really answering the question either.

Comment: @nkint TTo narrow the focus of the question, perhaps you could add more information about your expectations of the user's ability at gross and fine motor control. I'm asking about this because making a touchscreen UI accessible requires knowledge of the user's motor control abilities. Another piece of information that would help is the size of the display/touchscreen. Is the device the size of a smartphone, tablet, larger?

Comment: Big buttons is definitely a good thing. But in the context of a hospital, ignoring motion disabilities seems like a big oversight.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering if a touch-control is suitable at all. The question suggests the controls are on the same surface as the actual video (please correct me if I got this wrong). That means that the screen has to be in a position that is comfortable to watch, and is comfortable to touch. I find it hard to imagine a position for somebody lying in a bed where both are the case at the same time. At the very least, the patient would have to lift their arm quite a bit to reach for the screen. That does not seem a very comfortable position to hold and manipulate things like sliders or on-screen buttons.